# How can I make geom_area() leave a gap for missing values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I plot using `geom_area()` I expect it to perform a lot like `geom_bar()`, but I'm a little perplexed by this behavior for missing values.

```
    require(dplyr)
    require(ggplot2)

    set.seed(1)

    test <- data.frame(x=rep(1:10,3), y=abs(rnorm(30)), z=rep(LETTERS[1:3],10)) %>% arrange(x,z) 

# I also have no idea why geom_area needs the data.frame to be sorted first.

    test[test$x==4,"y"] <- NA

    ggplot(test, aes(x, y, fill=z)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack")
```

Produces this stacked bar chart.
[image: Graph using stack_bar()]

However, if I change to stack_area() it interpolates across the missing values.

```
> ggplot(test, aes(x, y, fill=z)) + geom_area(stat="identity", position="stack")
Warning message:
Removed 3 rows containing missing values (position_stack).
```

[image: Graph using stack_area()]

If I add in `na.rm=FALSE` or `na.rm=TRUE` it makes no difference.

> ggplot(test, aes(x, y, fill=z)) + geom_area(stat="identity", position="stack", na.rm=TRUE)
>   Warning message:
>   Removed 3 rows containing missing values (position_stack)

[image: Graph with na.rm=TRUE]

> ggplot(test, aes(x, y, fill=z)) + geom_area(stat="identity", position="stack", na.rm=FALSE)
>   Warning message:
>   Removed 3 rows containing missing values (position_stack).

[image: Graph with na.rm=FALSE]

Obviously, whatever I'm trying isn't working. How can I show a gap in the series with `stack_area()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the problem has to do with how the values are stacked. The error message tells you that the rows containing missing values were removed, so there is simply no gap present in the data that your are plotting.

However, `geom_ribbon`, of which `geom_area` is a special case, leaves gaps for missing values. `geom_ribbon` plots an area as well, but you have to specify the maximum and minimum y-values. So the trick can be done by calculating these values manually and then plotting with `geom_ribbon()`. Starting with your data frame `test`, I create the `ymin` and `ymax` data as follows:

```
test$ymax <-test$y
test$ymin <- 0
zl <- levels(test$z)
for ( i in 2:length(zl) ) {
   zi <- test$z==zl[i]
   zi_1 <- test$z==zl[i-1]
   test$ymin[zi] <- test$ymax[zi_1]
   test$ymax[zi] <- test$ymin[zi] + test$ymax[zi]
}
```

and then plot with `geom_ribbon`:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=x,ymax=ymax,ymin=ymin, fill=z)) + geom_ribbon()
```

This gives the following plot:

[image]

Comment: following up issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454277/can-you-make-geom-ribbon-leave-a-gap-for-missing-values?answertab=votes#tab-top