# Can you make geom_ribbon leave a gap for missing values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I am following up a discussion started at: [How can I make geom_area() leave a gap for missing values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116606/how-can-i-make-geom-area-leave-a-gap-for-missing-values). It seems like geom_ribbon is not longer leaving gaps for missing values. Please try to execute the reproducible example in the attached link. I cannot get the answer described. Can you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a bug in `ggplot2`, there seems to be a missing `handle_na` function that needs to be added as a part of a new unified way of dealing with NA values.

### Update:

The first post here refined an entire new `ggproto` to fix this, but I realized 
that as a one-liner workaround you can just override the `handle_na` function like I do in the code below (`# fix GeomRibbon`):

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)

set.seed(1)

test <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, 3), y = abs(rnorm(30)), z = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 10)) 
           %>% arrange(x, z)

test[test$x == 4, "y"] <- NA

test$ymax <- test$y
test$ymin <- 0
zl <- levels(test$z)
for (i in 2:length(zl)) {
    zi <- test$z == zl[i]
    zi_1 <- test$z == zl[i - 1]
    test$ymin[zi] <- test$ymax[zi_1]
    test$ymax[zi] <- test$ymin[zi] + test$ymax[zi]
}


# fix GeomRibbon
GeomRibbon$handle_na <- function(data, params) {  data }

ggplot(test, aes(x = x,y=y, ymax = ymax, ymin = ymin, fill = z)) +
  geom_ribbon() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10)
```

yielding:

[image]

Comment: I posted the issue and Hadley fixed it almost immediately. https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/commit/a760ff627582da59f938af14b0f01d54a4a97aa7